# How to play an animation on click in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

All I want is to play a 2D animation when I click. The problem Is that I have no idea how the animator controller works.

Comment: Come on stack overflow, this is the perfect time for a lmgtfy link...

Comment: If you have no idea how something works then do your research first: [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animator.html). Then come back with a pertinent question.

Comment: Proph - this site is really only suitable for more specific questions.  I hate the animator (fuck the animator) but you can't really get general sort of tutorials on here you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going to googles third page, I found a question with an answer which had `animator.Play("anim");` and that finally worked. Of course I had to make the animation controller, but I didn't have to make any transitioning stuff. All i could see before is some complicated Animator Controller transitioning and too old code like `animation.Play`. Oh and I found that on freaking quora.com .